# Find the maximal domain of the complex arcsine

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that I can find the complex inverse of $\sin z$ by setting $w=\sin z$ and solving for $z$.  It eventually becomes

$$ z = -i\ln(iw+\sqrt{1-w^2}) $$

and I know that we can express this complex square-root in exponential form to bring out the multi-valued-ness of this.  What I'm unsure of is how to find the largest domain on which such a function would be analytic.  I would guess that taking an analytic branch of the logarithm is a good start.  And I believe the square-root is not analytic on all of $\mathbb C$ but that it is on a branch.

I may be misunderstanding exactly how branches work, but it seems to me that so long as we pick a branch on which the relation is single-valued then the function is analytic on that branch.  So if we pick a branch of the logarithm coinciding with $\arg(x)$ for any $x\in \mathbb C$, then we will have an analytic function.  That is to say, we map $\sqrt{1-w^2} = |1-w^2|^{1/2}e^{\frac i 2 \arg(1-w^2)}$ where the function $\arg(\cdot)$ takes values in the range $[a,a+2\pi)$ for some choice of $a\in \mathbb R$. After this choice we make another choice of branch for the logarithm.  Now we have an analytic function?

I think I have something wrong here but I'm fuzzy on exactly what.  Something that doesn't sit right with me is that I don't think $\sqrt{\ \cdot \ }$ has a branch the same way that $\ln(\cdot)$ does, because $\sqrt{1} = e^{0}$ or $e^{i\pi}=-1$.  This demonstrates to me that making a choice of $\arg(1-w^2)$ unique in some interval of width $2\pi$ isn't sufficient.  Does it have to be chosen uniquely in an interval of width $\pi$ instead?

And I think this sort of argument will, if I can make it correctly, give me an analytic function--but then how do I determine the largest domain on which it is analytic?  I think this requires at least that the domain of $\ln$ not include negative reals.  Is that the only restriction?

Comment: There is not a unique largest domain on which such a holomorphic function can be defined... As you apparently suspect already, _any_ region that short-circuits the ambiguity of the branch points (that is, "kills monodromy") will do.

Comment: @paulgarrett Fair point.  I really just used the definite article by accident though.  Is there a description of a class of domains which are all individually maximal?  I *think* what I've described is a branch which is analytic ... where $z=\arcsin w$ and $iw+\sqrt{1-w^2}$ is not a negative real number?  But even if we have a domain on which we know this is analytic, how would we know that any one of them is maximal?

Comment: The Monodromy Theorem is the general idea that addresses this: the homotopy $\pi_1$ of $\mathbb C$ take-away the branch points acts on "branches", and the domain must be shrunken exactly so that the modified homotopy group's action becomes trivial. An easy way is to restrict to a simply-connected open, but that's by far not the only way.